# Programmatically "select all" in QSpinBox

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Is there a way to do this? To do it manually, I right click inside of the Spin Box and choose "Select All". The end goal is to present the spin box in a "selected" state. I want to know if this can be done without subclassing QSpinBox (out of pure laziness).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QSpinBox inherits QAbstractSpinBox, and it has a method called `selectAll()`.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qspinbox.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractspinbox.html#selectAll

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qspinbox-members.html

Hope that helps.